# Python numbers game reverse

Tags: python

So I have to make a "game" on python were I think of a number and it tries to guess the number. I have to tell it if it's higher or lower than the number it guessed and continue from there. So far I have it doing what I need but I have no idea how to make python remember what numbers it's guessed. So If I tell it to guess a number between 1 and 10 and it guesses 7, I say it's too high it then guesses 4 and I say it's too low it might then guess and 8. Well I can't have it guess a number higher than 7 since I said it's lower than that already. Is there any way to make it remember that?
Here's my code:

```
from random import randrange
def lowHigh():
    l = input ("Please input the low number range.")
    numl = eval(l)
    h = input ("Please input the high number range.")
    numh = eval(h)
    guess = randrange(1,numh + 1)
    print (guess)
    while True:
        ask = input("Is this number correct? y for yes or n for no.")
        if ask == 'y':
            print("Yay! I guessed right!")
            break
        else:
            lowOrHigh = input ("Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.")
            if lowOrHigh == 'h':
                guess = randrange(numl,guess-1)
                print(guess)
            else:
                guess = randrange(guess+1,numh)
                print(guess)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two different numbers to indicate the lowest and highest guesses.

When the computer guesses a number and its higher actual number, you can make the highest  = that number.

Same way when the computer guesses a number and its lower than actual number, you can make the lower = that number.

And each time you take random number between these two lowest and highest number only.

The code would look like -

```
from random import randrange
def lowHigh():
    l = input ("Please input the low number range.")
    numl = eval(l)
    h = input ("Please input the high number range.")
    numh = eval(h)
    lowest = l
    highest = h
    while True:
        guess = randrange(lowest,highest+1)
        print (guess)
        ask = input("Is this number correct? y for yes or n for no.")
        if ask == 'y':
            print("Yay! I guessed right!")
            break
        else:
            lowOrHigh = input ("Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.")
            if lowOrHigh == 'h':
               highest = guess - 1
            else:
               lowest = guess
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was think but I have no idea how to do that. The code I've provided is basically my extent of Python. :l But thank you!

Comment: I had to change a few things because I used the lowest = guess and sometimes it would guess the same number twice. so I did lowest = guess +1 and so far haven't had any problem?

Comment: Also, would advice if the answers are working to your satisfaction, you accept them (only if they work to your satisfaction) , this is general to all questions . Would really help the community remain motivated to produce good answers for all , and would help people who have same questions in future.

Comment: Got it! Didn't know I could do that till now :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can save the numbers it guessed in a list and then you check if a new guess is already in the list or not.
initialise an empty list like so:

```
guessed=[]
```

and then you can append guesses made by your program into the list

```
guessed.append(guess)
```

Comment: So (dumbing it down for myself) guessed=[ ] is creating the list an guessed.append(guess) is putting the guesses into the list. How do I get python to check the list before guessing a new number?

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:**

```
from random import randrange
import time


def guessNumber(min_no, max_no):
    """ Select number from the range. """
    try:
        return randrange(min_no, max_no)
    except ValueError:
        return min_no


def userNoInput(msg):
    """ Get Number into from the user. """
    while 1:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter Only Number string."
            continue

def findMe():
    """ 
        1. Get Lower and Upeer Value number from the User.
        2. time sleep to guess number for user in between range.
        3. While infinite loop.
        4. Get guess number from the Computer.
        5. User can check guess number and tell computer that guess number if correct ror not.
        6. If Correct then print msg and break While loop.
        7. If not Correct then 
             Ask Computer will User that guess number is Greate or Lower then Actual number. 
            7.1. If Greater then Set Max limit as guess number.  
            7.2. If Not Greater then Set Min limit as guess number.
            7.3. Continue While loop
    """
    min_no = userNoInput("Please input the low number range:")
    max_no = userNoInput("Please input the high number range:")
    print "Guess any number between %d and %d."%(min_no, max_no)
    max_no += 1
    time.sleep(2)


    while True:
        guess = guessNumber(min_no, max_no)
        print "Computer guess Number:-", guess
        ask = raw_input("Is this number correct? y for Yes or n for No:")
        if ask.lower() == 'y':
            print("Yay! I guessed right!")
            break
        else:
            lowOrHigh = raw_input("Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.")
            if lowOrHigh.lower() == 'h':
                #- As guess number is higher then set max number to guess number. 
                max_no = guess
            else:
                #- As guess number is lower then set min number to guess number. 
                min_no = guess

findMe()
```

Output:

```
Please input the low number range:10
Please input the high number range:20
Guess any number between 10 and 20.
Computer guess Number:- 14
Is this number correct? y for Yes or n for No:n
Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.l
Computer guess Number:- 19
Is this number correct? y for Yes or n for No:n
Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.h
Computer guess Number:- 17
Is this number correct? y for Yes or n for No:n
Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.h
Computer guess Number:- 16
Is this number correct? y for Yes or n for No:n
Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.h
Computer guess Number:- 15
Is this number correct? y for Yes or n for No:y
Yay! I guessed right!
```

**Note:**

Python 2.7 : `raw_input()` method, `print` is statement.

Python 3.X : `input()` method, `print` is function.

Answer (score 0):

> Its very similar to a Binary Search Algorithm

Its just that the usual mid value in such algorithms can be replaced by `randrange(Low,High)`

I'm not sure if this is a working code but I suggest you do it recursively:

```
items= range(l,h)
def random_search(ask, items, l, h):
    """
    Random search function.
    Assumes 'items' is a sorted list.
    The search range is [low, high)
    """
    ask = input("Is this number correct? y for yes or n for no.")
    lowOrHigh = input ("Is this number too high or low? h for high, l for low.")
    elem = randrange(l,h)

    if ask == 'y':
        return elem
    elif h == l:
        return False
    elif lowOrHigh == 'h':
        items= range(l,elem)
        return random_search(ask, items, l, elem)
    else:
        items= range(elem, h)
        return random_search(ask, items, elem, h)
```