# Basic Python code not Working

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am newbie to Python. 
  Here is my Code that implements binary search to find the guessed number .I cant figure it out correctly how to make my code work.
  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
print"Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"



guessed=False
while not guessed:
    lo=0
    hi=100
    mid=(lo+hi)/2
    print'Is you Secret Number'+str(mid)+'?'
    print"Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.",
    print"Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low",
    print"Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly"
    x=raw_input()
    if(x=='c'):
        guessed=True
    elif(x=='h'):
        #Too High Guess
        lo=mid+1
    elif(x=='l'):
        lo=mid-1
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
print'Game Over','Your Secret Number was'+str()
```

Comment: This will be helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934834/python-numbers-game-reverse/30935878#30935878

Comment: Several things wrong with this.  First, you reset `lo` to zero at the start of the loop every time, so whatever you set later on is changed back to zero.  Move `lo=0` to before the loop.  That's a start anyway, more to go though.  Also see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: you too @cdarke thanks. for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following points need to apply code:

1. Define lower and upper limit outside of `for` loop becsue if we define inside `while loop`, every time `lo` and `hi` variable will create with `0` and `100` value respectively.
2. Give variable name according to variable work.

`lower = 0
 higher = 100`

3. God practice to **Write function** to wrap your code.
4. As guess number is **higher** then set **Max Number** to guess number.
   As guess number is **lower** then set **Min Number** to guess number.

**Demo:**

```
import time


def userNoInput(msg):
    """ Get Number into from the user. """
    while 1:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter Only Number string."
            continue


def guessGame():
    """
        1. Get Lower and Upeer Value number from the User.
        2. time sleep to guess number for user in between range.
        3. While infinite loop.
        4. Get guess number from the Computer.
        5. User can check guess number and tell computer that guess number if correct ror not.
        6. If Correct then print msg and break While loop.
        7. If not Correct then 
            Ask Computer will User that guess number is Greate or Lower then Actual number. 
            7.1. If Greater then Set Max limit as guess number.  
            7.2. If Not Greater then Set Min limit as guess number.
            7.3. Continue While loop
    """
    min_no = userNoInput("Please input the low number range:")
    max_no = userNoInput("Please input the high number range:")
    print "Guess any number between %d and %d."%(min_no, max_no)
    time.sleep(2)

    while True:
        mid = (min_no+max_no)/2
        print'Is you Secret Number'+str(mid)+'?'
        print"Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.",
        print"Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low",
        print"Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly"
        x=raw_input().lower()
        if(x=='c'):
            print'Game Over','Your Secret Number was'+str(mid)
            break
        elif(x=='h'):
            #- As guess number is higher then set max number to guess number. 
            max_no=mid - 1
        elif(x=='l'):
            #- As guess number is lower then set min number to guess number. 
            min_no = mid + 1
        else:
            print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")

guessGame()
```

**Output:**

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python guess_game.py 
Please input the low number range:1
Please input the high number range:100          
Guess any number between 1 and 100.
Is you Secret Number50?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
h
Is you Secret Number25?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
h
Is you Secret Number12?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
l
Is you Secret Number18?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
h
Is you Secret Number15?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
l
Is you Secret Number16?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
l
Is you Secret Number17?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter'l' to indicate the guess is too low Enter'c'to indicate I guessed correctly
c
Game Over Your Secret Number was17
```

Comment: @M.UsmanSiddiqui: Welcome. Free to ask question on stackoverflow or me[I am reachable by email vivekbsable@gmail.com or skpe vivek.igp]

Comment: i had dropped an email check it out bro.